# cannot login after changing key ssh

Tags: ssh

My problem is that one user forgot his ssh passphrase for key, so i had to generate new one and install it on all environments.

Here's the thing: I have created key without any passphrase and copied it to all servers (single key pair on all servers) so every server has the same id_rsa key and id_rsa.pub key added to authorized_keys. And the problem is I still can't login to these servers.

output:

```
user@server1:~$ ssh user@server2
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa': <empty> 
Permission denied (publickey).
user@server1:~$
```

I have no idea what may cause the problem. I have generated those keys twice, tried to use ssh-add command to be sure that system can see those keys but nothing helped.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: 1) You store only the public key to the server (as the name tells). If your key does not have passphrase, client will not ask for it. How did you generate it?

Comment: whole environment uses the same private and public key to authorize so I need copy of private key on every single server.

Comment: I have generated it by simply typing 'ssh-keygen'.

Comment: Use `ssh -vvv` to provide more diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

Remove ".ssh" forlder in every user folder (e.g. `/home/user1`), then try to generate new keys again. ".ssh" folder is hidden by default, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to showing the hidden file and folders.

Also, you can ssh to a system as password-less :

`ssh-keygen`

`ssh-copy-id user@host`

After the `key` is copied, `ssh` into the machine is password-less :

`ssh user@host`

Comment: I have even tried to delete whole account and recreate it - didn't help.

Comment: do you remove ".ssh" folder for every user?

Comment: I have used 'userdel -r user' and then created it again and copied pair of keys.

Comment: @Thomas please refresh my answer again, i explain complete. maybe can help you.

Comment: Ehh, sadly didn't help.

Comment: Do i have to turn on authentication with password to create connection and after success disable it again or somehting?

Comment: exactly what is your purpose?

Comment: do you try for restart `ssh` service?

Comment: I've got 2 servers with disabled password authentication. On both servers exists account named user. The user uses the same id_rsa and id_rsa.pub on both servers, so the id_rsa and authorized_keys on bot servers looks the same but after trying to log in I get an error with message: Permission denied (publickey). as if those keys didn't exist or something.

Comment: @Thomas i'm sorry, i cannot help you more than this.

Comment: i work with `ssh` in linux, like my answer. so i dont know more.

Answer (score 0):

After change your key, type:

```
ssh-add
```

And to verify, type:

```
ssh-add -l
```

And verify with md5sum your id_rsa.pub in your host and authorized_keys on the server.